# Downloading a file from server and save it in client

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am currently developing an ASP.net application, where I generate a word document in server and I want to save it in client machine who access that feature with out user interactions. How can I download it and save it in client machine, using Javascript?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that JS won't let you do that without user interaction, because this sounds **exactly** like something that malware would want to do (whereas legitimate applications wouldn't mind the user being aware of their actions).

Comment: you can force Open/Save As dialog (IE) by adding "attachment" header using the Response.Headers

Answer (score 3):

you cann't save it in clients machine with out knowledge of client.

You can give a `link` of the word document,user need to click on the link and save it in his machine.

```
 <a href="serverLink.doc" >Click to Save Word document</a>
```

Note: you cant do any manipulation on client PC by using Javascript or any scripting language

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of this :

CASE 1 :

```
private static string GetWebTest1(string url)        
{            
     System.Net.WebClient Client = new WebClient();            
     return Client.DownloadString(url);        
}
```

CASE 2 :

```
 private static string GetWebTest2(string url)        
 {            
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
      WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
      Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();            
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);            
      return reader.ReadToEnd();        
 }
```

Comment: ok i figured it for C# but for javascript it can be SIMILAR TO anishmarokey'S answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) and you are doing bulk downloads then do use [`WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx). Sometimes we do bulk download but user get the impression that system stuck or fail somewhere and start hitting `refresh`. Avoid that!